# Object as object property name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Is this possible in javascript?

I'm trying to set the property name of an object to be a "HTMLInputElement":

```
var el = $('#something').get(0),
    obj = {};

obj[el] = 'some random data';
```

but I don't think it works :(

I get some error:

> ncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object
>   HTMLInputElement]

But I'm not sure if it's because of what I'm trying to do :)

However when I console.log(obj), it looks fine, with "object HTMLInputElement" inside key names, but I don't know if it's a real object, or just some string

Comment: Try using `obj[el.toString()] = 'some random data';` What you are trying to do is set the `HTMLInputElement` object itself as a key.

Comment: Seems to be working for me [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAL4J/1/)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I guess that `obj` is later iterated and pushed in a jQuery object. But keys are stored as strings, which are obviously invalid jQuery selectors --> Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is certainly possible. Anything between the property brackets is allowed. The `toString()` method is called.

```
// Test case:
var obj = {};
obj[document.body] = '1';
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));  // Shows {"[object HTMLBodyElement]":"1"}
```

---

### Problem

After reading your comments, I see what you're trying to do: Creating a map of DOM elements, for later use in a jQuery wrapper. This does not work, because, as I mentioned, keys are strings.

```
// Your intentions:
var obj = {};
var body = $('body').get(0);
obj[body] = {secret: 'Some text'};
$.each(obj, function(elem, data) {
    // Example:
    $(elem).text(data.secret);

    // Expected (filled in variables):
    $(body).text('Some text');

    // What actually happens
    $('[object HTMLBodyElement]').text('Some text');
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is an invalid jQuery selector!
});
```

### Solution

Use [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) objects for associating objects as key-value pairs, without coercing stringa. This is not well-supported, but that can be solved easily by using a [**polyfill**](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/source/browse/trunk/src/ses/WeakMap.js).

Comment: oh, so it's not a real object? It's just a string representation of the object? I wanted a real object so I can access it later when I'm iterating (as an object)..

Comment: @thelolcat All JavaScript keys are strings, including the numeric indices of arrays. For object-hashes, you might be interested in the [**`WeakMap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) object. **Polyfills** for compatibility [do exist](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/source/browse/trunk/src/ses/WeakMap.js).

Answer (score 1):

> oh, so it's not a real object? It's just a string representation of
>   the object? I wanted a real object so I can access it later when I'm
>   iterating (as an object).

You should probably construct a structure that hold both HTML element and the 'some random data'.

```
var el = $('#something').get(0),
    obj = {}, tmpArray = [];

tmpArray.push(el);
tmpArray.push('some random data');

obj['uniqueKey1'] = tmpArray; //['some random data', [object HTMLInputElement]]
```

Comment: that is what I'm going to. But I was thinking since javascript is more permissive than other languages, I could store it as the key name :)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax like `obj[el]` works only if `el` is a string not any object. So, for example, you can use some attr of an element for that (e.g. `id` or just `data-some-attr`)

Answer (score 1):

I did some test on what you are trying to achieve.

My test results shows that you cannot get the same `object` (which you set as key) when looping through the object.

```
var obj = {};
obj[document.body] = '1';

console.log(obj['[object HTMLBodyElement]']); /* prints 1 
# '[object HTMLBodyElement]' is the relative string
representation of the BODY object. */

console.log(obj[document.body]); /* prints 1
# because document.body converted into the relative string
'[object HTMLBodyElement]' */


for(var key in obj){

    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(key); // prints [object HTMLBodyElement] # which is string...
    }

}

console.log(document.body); //prints <body> #which is the real object.
```

What the above test shows is,

When you try to use any object(lets call it as keyObject) as key in some other `obj` using the `[]` notation, the keyObject is converted into some relative string and that string used as the key.

So when you loop over the `obj` you will get the relative string, not the real object.